# SQL Server and ADO.NET mis-generation

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

Has anyone tried to generate from two table like so

**Table1**

```
ID - PK  
Table2Id - FK (unique constraint and nullable)  
Log - String
```

**Table2**

```
Id - PK  
Request - String
```

When I generate from these tables, I expect a 0..1 to 0..1 relationship or when I make it not nullable, I expect a 0..1 to 1 relationship which also doesn't seem to generate correctly.

Does this work for other people?

Caveat: I do mostly java, so I am probably missing something simple.

Also, a follow on question. I am more used to hibernate and also find it strange that it generates a `Table1.Table2` field AND a `Table1.Table2Id` field. In hibernate world, it only generates the `Table1.Table2` field and when you call `Table1.Table2.Id` it gets the id not from Table2 but from the FK column of Table1 to avoid the database hit. I.e. why does C# bother having the second id field on generation as it seems like a waste?

Comment: by ADO do you mean Entity Framework?

Comment: Hibernate is an ORM, ADO.Net is sort of an API for accessing some sort of database. ORM is a higher level of abstraction. If you are used to thinking this way, you might want to have alook at Entity Framework or POCO instead.